# Make servlet filter for all 404 responses

Tags: java, servlets, filter, http-status-code-404

I want to make a Custom filter which extends javax.filter, when 404 is the status of the response to return static html page. But it does not work and I am wondering why.
Here is my filter:

```
@WebFilter("/*")
public class PageNotFoundFilter implements Filter {

    @Override
    public void doFilter(final ServletRequest request, final ServletResponse response, final FilterChain filterChain)
            throws IOException, ServletException {
        HttpServletResponse httpResponse = (HttpServletResponse) response;
        if (httpResponse.getStatus() == 404) {
            httpResponse.sendRedirect("pages/PageNotFound.html");
        }
        filterChain.doFilter(request, response);

    }
```

But nothing happens, why?

Note: I do not want to use:

```
<error-page>
  <error-code>404</error-code>
  <location>/pages/PageNotFound.html</location>
</error-page>
```

But Filter

Comment: Can you post your web.xml?

Comment: Have you debugged or placed logging statements to see if your filter is being invoked?

Comment: I do not have web.xml

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You test the status code before the request is processed (and before the 404 error is set).

So you need to test the status code after you have called `filterChain.doFilter(request, response);`

But this will not work either because when `response.sendError(404)` was called the response is committed and you can't redirect.

Therefore it is best to use the `<error-page>` mechanism.

Comment: If I do that: I have 500
<b>sendRedirect() after the response has been committed</b>

Comment: That is the reason why should use `<error-page>`. Once a response was committed you can't change its headers.

Comment: So there is no way to catch 404 using filter?

Comment: Yes, I checked the sequence, filters are called before the the process of the requests. Thanks. I will need web.xml with error-page in it.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried using the `<error-page>` element in the `web.xml`?

I think it's a good alternative to this - only configuration, no code.
Here is an example of how you can do this:

```
<error-page>
    <error-code>404</error-code>
    <location>pages/PageNotFound.html</location>
</error-page>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can redirect in a Filter. You just need to make sure **not calling filterChain.doFilter() afterwards**. If you do so it will lead to the chain continuing with the request even though you already set a redirect on the response leading to the error described above.

Correct implementation of your filter would be:

```
    public void doFilter(final ServletRequest request, final ServletResponse response, final FilterChain filterChain)
        throws IOException, ServletException {
    HttpServletResponse httpResponse = (HttpServletResponse) response;
    if (httpResponse.getStatus() == 404) {
        httpResponse.sendRedirect("pages/PageNotFound.html");
    } else {
        filterChain.doFilter(request, response);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to call the filter chain *first* before checking the response.